# What does the subset argument do in pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

The public documentation for [`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) says

> **subset** : *IndexSlice*
>   An argument to `DataFrame.loc` that restricts which elements `formatter` is applied to.

But [looking at the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cc3daa6f7e140e870d57c3b02a5d2142e11d09c9/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L478), that's not quite true... what is this `_non_reducing_slice` stuff?

```
    if subset is None:
        row_locs = range(len(self.data))
        col_locs = range(len(self.data.columns))
    else:
        subset = _non_reducing_slice(subset)
        if len(subset) == 1:
            subset = subset, self.data.columns

        sub_df = self.data.loc[subset]
```

---

Use case: I want to format a particular row, but I get an error when I naively follow the documentation with something that works fine with `.loc[]`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([dict(a=1,b=2,c=3),dict(a=3,b=5,c=4)])
>>> df = df.set_index('a')
>>> print df
   b  c
a
1  2  3
3  5  4
>>> def J(x):
...     return '!!!%s!!!' % x
...
>>> df.style.format(J, subset=[3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 372, in format
    sub_df = self.data.loc[subset]
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1325, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 841, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 189, in _has_valid_tuple
    if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1418, in _has_valid_type
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'None of [[3]] are in the [columns]'
>>> df.loc[3]
b    5
c    4
Name: 3, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[[3]]
   b  c
a
3  5  4
```

---

OK, I tried using `IndexSlice` and it seems flaky -- works in some cases, doesn't work in others, at least in Pandas 0.20.3:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:34:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> r = np.arange(16).astype(int)
>>> colors = 'red green blue yellow'.split()
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[colors[i] for i in r//4], b=r%4, c=r*100)).set_index(['a','b'])
>>> print df
             c
a      b
red    0     0
       1   100
       2   200
       3   300
green  0   400
       1   500
       2   600
       3   700
blue   0   800
       1   900
       2  1000
       3  1100
yellow 0  1200
       1  1300
       2  1400
       3  1500
>>> df.loc[idx['yellow']]
      c
b
0  1200
1  1300
2  1400
3  1500
>>> def J(x):
...     return '!!!%s!!!' % x
...
>>> df.style.format(J,idx['yellow'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 372, in format
    sub_df = self.data.loc[subset]
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1325, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 836, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 948, in _getitem_lowerdim
    return self._getitem_nested_tuple(tup)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1023, in _getitem_nested_tuple
    obj = getattr(obj, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1541, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1081, in _getitem_iterable
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1418, in _has_valid_type
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: "None of [['yellow']] are in the [columns]"
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.20.3'
```

In pandas 0.24.2 I get a similar error but slightly different:

```
>>> df.style.format(J,idx['yellow'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 401, in format
    sub_df = self.data.loc[subset]
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1494, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 868, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 969, in _getitem_lowerdim
    return self._getitem_nested_tuple(tup)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1048, in _getitem_nested_tuple
    obj = getattr(obj, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1902, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1205, in _getitem_iterable
    raise_missing=False)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1246, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: u"None of [Index([u'yellow'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.24.2'
```

Oh wait -- I wasn't specifying enough index information; this works:

```
df.style.format(J,idx['yellow',:])
```

Comment: I have used this argument to apply formatting to some, but not all, cells in a dataframe.  Is there some case where its ultimate behavior is surprising you?  For example, a case where calling `format(..., subset=s)` gives different results than `df.loc[s]`?  I think that would qualify as a bug.

Comment: added use case that's causing me grief

Comment: It's says right there that `[3]` is not your column. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to apply my Formatter to a portion of the data frame, in particular one row, that is selected by `.loc[]`, which is exactly what `3` or `[3]` does..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the behavior you showed is not ideal.

```
>>> df = (pandas.DataFrame([dict(a=1,b=2,c=3),
                            dict(a=3,b=5,c=4)])
            .set_index('a'))
>>> df.loc[[3]]
   b  c
a      
3  5  4
>>> df.style.format('{:.2f}', subset=[3])
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

You can work around this issue by passing a fully-formed `pandas.IndexSlice` as the subset argument:

```
>>> df.style.format('{:.2f}', subset=pandas.IndexSlice[[3], :])
```

Since you asked what `_non_reducing_slice()` is doing, its goal is reasonable (ensure a subset does not reduce dimensionality to Series).  Its implementation treats a list as a sequence of *column names*:

> From [pandas/core/indexing.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c0f6428b097f6e1a1765d8d07cb695169f442e66/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2477-L2506):
>
> ```
> def _non_reducing_slice(slice_):
>     """
>     Ensurse that a slice doesn't reduce to a Series or Scalar.
>
>     Any user-paseed `subset` should have this called on it
>     to make sure we're always working with DataFrames.
>     """
>     # default to column slice, like DataFrame
>     # ['A', 'B'] -> IndexSlices[:, ['A', 'B']]
>     kinds = (ABCSeries, np.ndarray, Index, list, str)
>     if isinstance(slice_, kinds):
>         slice_ = IndexSlice[:, slice_] 
>     ...
> ```

I wonder if the documentation could be improved:  in this case, the exception raised with `subset=[3]` matches the behavior of `df[[3]]` rather than `df.loc[[3]]`.

Comment: OK. It would be great if the documentation matched the code. (such an example as you give would be really helpful, especially since selecting one or more rows is a rather common thing)

Comment: so.... you answered the question of what I was trying to do, but not the question I asked... what exactly is `subset` really doing in the code?

Comment: But the document does say that `subset`: *IndexSlice*.

Comment: GAH! How did I miss that? :(

Comment: now I just have to figure out what IndexSlice does :/

Comment: @JasonS, you're right that an example in the documentation would be helpful.  It seems like the behavior of subset might actually be reflecting `df[[3]]` rather than `df.loc[[3]]`.

Comment: Grr. `IndexSlice` doesn't solve the problem, either, at least not in some cases. (see my latest edit to the question)

Comment: oh, never mind, I wasn't handling multi-indices correctly

Answer (score 1):

It indeed does what it supposed to do.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))

df.style.background_gradient(subset=[0,1])

df.style.background_gradient()
```

gives:

[image]
[image]

respectively.

Comment: In your case, it does. In general, it does not.