# How to apply style selectively to rows of specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to flag the anomalies in the *"desired"* columns (`desired_D` to `desired_L`). Here, an anomaly is defined as any value `<1500` and `>400000` in each row.

See below for the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists
data = { 
         'A':['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5'],
         'B':[1,1,1,1,1],
         'C':[1,2,3,5,9],
         'desired_D':[12005, 18190, 1021, 13301, 31119],
        'desired_E':[11021, 19112, 19021, 15, 24509 ],
        'desired_F':[10022,19910, 19113,449999, 25519],
        'desired_G':[14029, 29100, 39022, 24509, 412271],
        'desired_H':[52119,32991,52883,69359,57835],
         'desired_J':[41218, 52991,55121,69152,79355],
         'desired_K': [43211,7672991,56881,211,77342],
          'desired_L': [31211,42901,53818,62158,69325],
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

Currently, my code flags columns `B`, and `C` inclusively (I want to exclude them).

The revised code looks like this:

```
# function to flag the anomaly in each row- this flags columns B and C as well (I want to exclude these columns)

dont_format_cols = ['B','C']

def flag_outliers(s, dont_format_cols):
    if s.name in dont_format_cols:
        return '' # or None, or whatever df.style() needs
    else:
        s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
        indexes = (s<1500)|(s>400000)
        return ['background-color: red' if v else '' for v in indexes]

styled = df.style.apply(flag_outliers, axis=1)
styled
```

The error after edits

[image]

Desired output:  should exclude `B` and `C`,refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: [`df.apply(..., axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) applies your outlier-styling function (column-wise) to ***all*** of df. If you only want to apply it to some columns, then inspect the series name `s.name` inside the styling function, as in [Pandas style function to highlight specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655004/202229)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the subset argument do in pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203022/what-does-the-subset-argument-do-in-pandas-io-formats-style-styler-format)

Comment: Please state your question accurately. *"How to flag anomalies..."* is a red herring (you're not actually looking for an anomaly-detection heuristic), you're trying to selectively apply styling.

Answer (score 1):

[`df.style.apply(..., axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) applies your outlier-styling function (column-wise) to ***all*** of df's columns. If you only want to apply it to some columns, **use the `subset` argument.**

---

EDIT: I wasn't aware `df.style.apply()` had a `subset` argument, I had proposed these hacky approaches:

1: **inspect the series name `s.name` inside the styling function**, like the solution [Pandas style function to highlight specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655004/202229).

```
### Hack solution just hardwire it into the body of `flag_outliers()` without adding in an extra arg `dont_format_cols`    
def flag_outliers(s):
    dont_format_cols = ['B','C']
    if s.name in dont_format_cols:
        return '' # or None, or whatever df.style() needs
    else:
        # code to apply formatting
```

2: Another hack approach: add a second arg `dont_format_cols` to your function `flag_outliers(s, dont_format_cols)`. Now you have to pass it in in the apply call, so you'll need a lambda:

```
styled = df.style.apply(lambda s: flag_outliers(s, dont_format_cols), axis=1)
```

and:

```
def flag_outliers(s, dont_format_cols):
    if s.name in dont_format_cols:
        return '' # or None, or whatever df.style() needs
    else:
        # code to apply formatting
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for me, I think I am not getting something. I used your code (pls refer to my revised code) and got an error `TypeError: flag_outliers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dont_format_cols' `.

Comment: @RickyTricky: it does work. Obviously since we added a second arg `dont_format_cols`, you either have to pass it, or default it. Or as. a quick hack, you can just hardwire it into the body of `flag_outliers()` without adding in an extra arg `dont_format_cols`

Comment: Revised the answer to show that. Please read about pandas `apply()` and look at some examples of when we declare lambda functions to pass in missing/extra parameters.

Comment: works now, after changing `axis=1` to `axis = 0`. Thanks

Comment: @RickyTricky: that might be wrong, `axis = 0` means apply the function row-wise.

Comment: `axis = 1`, it still captured  `B` and `C` in my code, which i don't want. can you share your replace your pseudocode with the full code and share the image of your output. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230742/discussion-between-rickytricky-and-smci).

Comment: why are you ignoring the `subset` argument?

Comment: @Attack68: I wasn't 'ignoring' it, aware it existed. I updated the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subset` argument. That is precisely its purpose to isolate styles to only specific regions.

i.e `df.style.apply(flag_outliers, axis=1, subset=<list of used columns>)`

You can see examples in the pandas Styler user guide documentation entitled finer slicing.